# Install ROS in Odroid N2+

Tags: ros, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, if in this link https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroi..., it says that Ubuntu 20.04 is supported so, it means that can I install ROS noetic?

We want to buy this SBC but we want to know if we can install ROS noetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381756/install-ros-in-odroid-n2+/) by [Esteban Castaño](https://answers.ros.org/users/77155/esteban-casta%C3%B1o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your link leads to the **Odroid-HC2**. ROS definitely works on the Odroid-HC2, because it's basically identical to the Odroid XU4, and I have personal experience running ROS on it.

Your question title says **Odroid N2+**. I don't have personal experience with it, but I'm 95% certain it will work with ROS, too - if it runs Ubuntu, it's very easy to install ROS as well.

One consideration is that these boards (like most SBCs) have ARM processors. For 99% of ROS packages this is not a problem, because almost everything runs on ARM as well. The only situation where it can become a problem is when you're running a hardware driver that depends on a proprietary binary library, and the hardware vendor only ships x64 binaries, not ARM. So if you want to use a specific sensor or so, better check beforehand if it supports ARM.

The other little quirk with the **Odroid XU4** that I've noticed is that it has the "big.Little" architecture (4 fast CPU cores and 4 slow CPU cores); the Odroid N2+ has the same architecture. This sometimes leads to situations where a ROS node gets scheduled on a slow CPU core (because to Ubuntu, all cores are the same) and suddenly runs much slower. This can be avoided by using `taskset` to explicitly schedule a node on the fast CPUs (4,5,6,7).

```
<launch>
  <!-- Switch on to specify specific CPUs which the driver may use -->
  <arg name="use_cpu_affinity" default="false"/>

  <!-- The CPUs to use, specified by their id, separated by commas and
       with no whitespace in between -->
  <arg name="cpu_affinity"         if="$(arg use_cpu_affinity)" default="4,5,6,7" />
  <arg name="cpu_affinity_set"     if="$(arg use_cpu_affinity)" value="taskset -c $(arg cpu_affinity)" />
  <arg name="cpu_affinity_set" unless="$(arg use_cpu_affinity)" value="" />

  <!-- Load driver -->
  <node machine="$(arg machine)" pkg="openni2_camera" type="openni2_camera_node" name="driver"
        launch-prefix="$(arg cpu_affinity_set)" output="screen">

[...]
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2021-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Esteban Castaño](https://answers.ros.org/users/77155/esteban-casta%C3%B1o/) on 2021-07-05**:
Thank u for your answer Martin. You're right, my question is about N2+, I was wrong about link.

Thanks again.

**Comment by [Esteban Castaño](https://answers.ros.org/users/77155/esteban-casta%C3%B1o/) on 2021-07-05**:
I wanted to send this link: https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-n2-with-4gbyte-ram-2/

I have another question: If with N2+ we could use ubuntu 20.04, Could we use ubuntu 18.04 and ROS melodic?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2021-07-06**:
It looks like that's possible: https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-n2/os_images/ubuntu

**Comment by [Esteban Castaño](https://answers.ros.org/users/77155/esteban-casta%C3%B1o/) on 2021-07-06**:
Thank u!!!